# How to use toilet paper

Tags: tips-and-tricks, local-customs, hygiene

If someone who has never used toilet paper ever travels to countries where only toilet paper is used - how could one learn to use toilet paper?

One of my (Asian) colleagues who is more of a friend confessed he is going paranoid after knowing the fact that he can only use toilet paper while travelling/staying in the US. He was alright being stationed in Dubai, where bidets/water is used to 'wash'. But no more looking further West. Are there any videos (on dummies)/tutorials that one can watch? Youtube doesn't have a tutorial on this either. Any other suggestions please

Comment: If toilet paper scares you, just wait until you see a toilet brush!

Comment: does he use bidet only or toilet paper + bidet and therefore is scared he may end up being not completely cleaner? Here in Italy we use the latter, that's why I'm asking.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Well, there is a website dedicated to this! It illustrates the process:

### [HowToWipeYourButt.com](http://www.howtowipeyourbutt.com/)

Here are the steps from that site in a nutshell:

1. You have to remain seated for the whole wiping process. Start out with a decent size wad of tissues, three balled-up squares should be enough. Reach around and behind your butt, and lean into the opposing cheek. Start wiping with the pointer, middle and ring fingers. Use moderate pressure and wipe at a cautious speed from front to back. Repeat this step with the same amount of tissue until the amount of remnants on the paper decreases by fifty percent.
2. For the second step, the amount of tissues should be reduced. Two crumbled squares should be enough at this stage. Follow the same directions of step 1 (with the reduced paper amount) but using more pressure with each wipe. Continue until the amount of remnant on the tissue decreases to a small amount.
3. The paper in the step should be decreased to one folded square. This really is sufficient. Repeat the same direction from step 1, but now you should be using significant pressure. As you pass over your anus, relax the sphincter and slightly press the pad of your middle finger into the opening, continue the progression from front to back. Repeat this step until there is very little to no remnants transferring onto the paper.
4. The final step which is often ignored, is to use a wet wipe, repeat step 3 until absolutely no remnants remain. This step is to ensure fresh, thorough clean that is second only to a bath or shower. This will reduce any staining, odor or itching that may occur later.
5. Flush, adjust your clothing, wash your hands with soap and water.

Also, [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YJCZOvjmBIA) explains it well.

A tip for your friend, always take a bottle of water when using a toilet with toilet paper only. This way things will be easier and much more like home.

Comment: Good point about the bottle of water. You see that a lost, in regions with large asian populations where western style toilets are standard (e.g. Caribbean)

Comment: I'm scared as to how you came across that site in the first place.

Comment: @FoxInFlame I am scared as to how you do not know Google.com.

Comment: @isanae the answer is old, but i will add some text once i have some free time later. thanks for the reminder.

Comment: @isanae done, I hope you approve now :D :D

Comment: I [disapprove with the seated part](http://deadspin.com/5424415/sitters-vs-standers--the-great-wipe-hope), but apart from that, it looks fabulous.

Comment: Instead of a bottle of water, you can also purchase 'wet toilet paper'. The toilet paper in public toilets is made to easily dissolve in water, which will result in you trying to clean yourself with crumbling paper if you wet it with a water bottle. The 'wet toilet paper' won't crumble as easily.

Comment: @isanae I'm with you and mostly because: before toilets were invented did humans sit? No,  there would be nowhere to sit!

Comment: @Summer the bottle of water is not to wet the toilet paper, rather to use directly for "washing". I believe the "wet toilet paper" is similar to baby wipes which serve the same purpose for babies.

Comment: Wet toilet paper does not dissolve in water. It clogs the toilet. Be careful.

Answer (score 12):

Maybe a different audience, but you could ask this question on parenting.se. A lot of parent are keen to know how to fully potty train their kids.

Searching in french on google made me find some examples in English on Youtube.
[Example 1](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0QHGqSV-q_o) [Example 2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QdwyM9wswTQ)

Answer (score 7):

Carry a [Travel Washlet](http://www.totousa.com/travel-washlet%C2%AE). I do. It's like portable civilization.

Comment: How do you use that?

Comment: Open the water cap, pull the two halves apart, fold the nozle out,  fill with water, direct the nozzle, press button. Totally SFW video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NBAY1GWjjaQ

Comment: So where are you going to get clean water from in a public toilet?

Answer (score 4):

"Carry a Travel Washlet. I do. It's like portable civilization." 168 Dollars ?

As a westener who learned to be clean whilst on my travels I carry a bottle of water when I'm out...easy. The one time I had to explain (I forgot it in my sister's bathroom & her husband asked) I got a blank look...

Why choose to be unclean just because those around you are...it's very uncomfortable once you learn the difference.

Comment: Half. A portable washlet is < $80 , has been even in '17, I am getting these since 2012. Never been 170 USD.

Answer (score 3):

So I'm Indian and I've been going around Europe. I like my butt being nice, clean and snuggly. So what I've been doing is carrying around​ a mug. I would wipe my butt with paper twice like in the accepted answer, then finish off with the water. Thanks to the toilet paper, one mug of water is sufficient for having a clean butt. That's important because in most European toilets, you don't have a water source within the cubicle but almost always have one right outside.

Answer (score 1):

For me using just toilet paper was like using sandpaper on the bottom and I dreaded it (having used it on one trip ) so I always have two things wet wipes and a small mug. I have never been convinced that paper can clean up as well as water. Clean with toilet paper as clean as you can and then try again with a water soaked paper and you can make out the difference. Before people comment please try it out once.
One word that I never knew till I heard it on two and a half men - skid marks - I had to Google what it was and then said Yuck. This is never heard of in areas using water/health faucet or a bidet.
So if you dread not having water - mug or bottle of water - soak toilet paper and use and use sos wet wipes. Please see that you have the flushable variation of wet wipes .
Please note that vegetarians can have another problem especially vegetarians in meat based countries where veg options are often loaded with cheese- you will get undigested oily residue that can be difficult to get rid off. So have liquid or paper soap ready if that is your challenge and be careful of what you eat.

Comment: While you describe what you feel is needed to get clean, this is not 'how to use toilet paper' as was asked. (I did not vote down but I feel this is not an answer to the question.)