# How to dry yourself after using the hand shower in the toilets?

Tags: culture, hygiene, asia

Inspired by this question [How to use toilet paper](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/21994/how-to-use-toilet-paper) I want to ask "How to use toilet without toilet paper".

During my travels through Asian countries, it was common to see the toilet  without toilet paper but with hand shower. For me it's still unbelievable, that somebody may use only hand shower afterwards.

I'm not asking about how to use those hand showers. I'm asking about what to do next. Dress on the wet body or what? Is it healthy? Can you get cold to wear wet underwear?

p.s. I know I can take a toilet paper with myself. I'm asking how to do it in common basis. Especially I want to understand how asian and muslim women cope with it. May be they have some secret private towel or using [three stones](http://www.salon.com/2013/03/13/a_history_of_toilet_hygiene_partner/) or have some other secret technics.

Comment: Bring your own toilet paper?

Comment: People do carry their own toilet paper while travelling in South Asia, because they know of it.

Comment: "Can you get cold to wear wet underwear?" Are you asking if you can contract [the common cold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_cold) by wearing wet underwear? "The common cold virus is typically transmitted via airborne droplets (aerosols), direct contact with infected nasal secretions, or fomites (contaminated objects)."

Comment: "If you fill frozen you will likely get flu... " that's what my grandma always said. Here is more science for @hippietrail http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2015/01/05/cold-weather-colds_n_6418802.html "molecules that detect viruses inside cells and then order the cell to produce interferon were less sensitive at colder temperatures. That lower sensitivity reduced production not only of interferon but also of proteins that chop up virus genes, block the release of virus and kill virus-infected cells."

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> I wish to hear answer from a female person as well [–  MikkaRin](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/25487/how-to-dry-yourself-after-using-the-hand-shower-in-the-toilets/25539#comment43460_25488)

Here's the female from India.
I haven't yet seen a toilet paper so there is no question of me knowing how to use it.

I don't carry nor I know of anyone carrying a *secret towel*.

Here's how I do it:
1. I don't directly place the shower's head towards my bottom since the water may splash towards my clothes and my feet, making them wet unnecessarily.
2. I turn the shower's head away from my body and collect little water in my palm.
3. Bring only that water (collected in my palm) near my bottom and apply it *only where it is needed*, carefully.
4. When I get up, I shake my bottom just to let water drops fall off.
5. Then I simply put on my underwear and pants and move out.

No, the water does not get shown through my clothes (or anyone else's) for the reason being that we mostly wear those cotton underwears which cover all our hip parts. The cotton full cover underwear soaks up the little water remaining on the buts which soon gets forgotten as we move out.

India being a conservative and not so rich country, the things like thongs (which don't cover the butts) are worn on special occasions and that too by upper middle class. If you are used to wearing thongs, then may be you'll have to carry the secret towel etc.

Answer (score -1):

I am an Asian we are used hand showers in toilet.
There are no health problems for using hand showers, the same action when you are used papers, 

about the cold its related to place you are traveling. Most Asian countries are average temperature so it's not a problem.

Comment: I wish to hear answer from a female person as well

Comment: The question is about how to dry yourself after using the hand showers.